# Scale y-tick labels in DC.js chart (D3.js underneath)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, dc.js, axis-labels

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically scale a chart's y-axis so the values are shown in single digits, with a exponential denotation at the top, effectively changing this:
[image: unscaled y axis]

To this:

[image: scaled y axis]

Note, this works automatically in e.g. Matlab/Matplotlib/etc., but I'm struggling to find a solution with the web plotting frameworks (maybe my search language is wrong)... I know D3.js is not a charting library, but I'd be open to a solution that works with the frontend DC.js or the backend D3.js

---

Edit based on @Gordon's answer below, I get the following graph using this

```
chart.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('.1e'));
```

[image: exponential format]

Is it somehow possible to move all of the e+6 to the top? Or do I need to write a custom scaling function and insert a separate text box myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dc.js, the axes are straight from [d3-axis](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/tree/v2.0.0).

Access them using `chart.xAxis()` and `chart.yAxis()`, and to reduce confusion, [do this in a separate statement](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis) from the rest of your chart initialization.

You can use [axis.tickFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/tree/v2.0.0#axis_tickFormat) to control how the tick text is formatted.

You can use [d3.format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#locale_format) to do automatic formatting. It seems like exponent or SI notation might suit what you're doing, although it's not exactly the same as having the exponent in a separate text element like in your screenshot.

Putting it together, this is pretty close

```
chart.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('.1e'))
```

The tick formatting question comes up a lot. I wonder where we could put this information so that people don't have to ask.

Comment: I was looking [here](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#yAxis), perhaps a note like the caution would be enough?

Comment: Thanks; that points to the d3-axis documentation, so maybe we could add a note that if you want to change ticks, that’s the place to look!

Comment: ahhhh, now I see, please excuse my lack of persistence/concentration in reading the dc.js docs!

Comment: Np! Always glad to earn some Fake Internet Points , always trying to improve the docs in small ways though.

Comment: `%e` didn't work for me, `.1e` got me closer, but see above for additional clarification

Comment: Thanks for following up. Guess I had printf on the brain. I've edited my answer.

Comment: did you see the update on the question? know if there's anyway to move the `e+6` to the top of the axis, instead of at each tick?

Comment: There is nothing built-in to do that. It's easy to add an extra text box using e.g. a `pretransition` hook (plenty of examples on SO). I guess the tricky part is that you have to decide on one exponent for all ticks - e.g. your example has both e+5 and e+6. Then you'd need to define a custom tick formatting function that uses the shared exponent. AFAIK D3 doesn't have anything for this - it considers each tick separately.